# Inserting multiple form attributes into sqlite3 db through PHP

Tags: php, database, forms, sqlite

Totes my bad if this has been asked elsewhere, I looked around but couldn't find exactly what my situation is. Basically I have a sqlite3 db created and populated on a server, I am trying to make an html form that connects to a php file, where a user can input some data that then gets inserted into a table.

The form works fine and connects, the problem lies in the PHP itself.

Here is the code for my php file:

```
<?php 
try{ 
$db = new PDO('sqlite:mydatabase.db');

$title = $_POST['title']; 
$subtitle = $_POST['subtitle']; 
$latitude = $_POST['latitude']; 
$longitude = $_POST['longitude']; 

$sql = "INSERT INTO stop (title,subtitle,latitude,longitude) VALUES (:title,:subtitle,:latitude,:longitude)"; 
$q = $db->prepare($sql); 

$q->bindParam(':title',$title); 
$q->bindParam(':subtitle',$subtitle); 
$q->bindParam(':latitude',$latitude); 
$q->bindParam(':longitude',$longitude); 
$q->execute(); 

echo 'inserted 1 row'; 
} 
catch(PDOException $e){ 
    echo 'exception:' . $e->getMessage(); 
} 
?>
```

As you can see the form submits four attributes: Title, Subtitle, Longitude, and Latitude. These attributes are then prepared into a query and executed on the database. The code successfully runs on the server and even echos that it inserted a row, however the database shows no changes.

Would really appreciate the help, have been banging my head against this one for awhile.

Thanks yo!

Comment: PDO doesn't throw exceptions by default. Try adding `print_r($q->errorInfo());` after `$q->execute();` and add the result to your question.

Comment: You sir helped me find the issue! Thanks dog!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out after adding `print_r($q->errorInfo());` after `$q->execute();` the problem made itself clear, which was that the database was in a read-only state. After digging around I found a nuance of PDO that you have to have both the database AND the folder it is inside in all permissions mode. Once changed everything worked perfectly!